# Removing nodes from a tree properly

Tags: java, tree, concurrentmodification

I have the following function that prunes a tree data structure :

```
public static void pruneTree(final ConditionTreeNode treeNode) {

    final List<ConditionTreeNode> subTrees = treeNode.getSubTrees();

    for (ConditionTreeNode current : subTrees) {
        pruneTree(current);
    }

    if(subTrees.isEmpty()) {
        final ConditionTreeNode parent = treeNode.getParent();
        parent.removeConditionTreeNode(treeNode);
    }

    if (treeNode.isLeaf()) {
        //this is the base case
        if (treeNode.isPrunable()) {
            final ConditionTreeNode parent = treeNode.getParent();
            parent.removeConditionTreeNode(treeNode);
        }
        return;
    }

}
```

and I want to know what the best way to prune this is.  I'm getting ConcurrentModificationExceptions currently, and I've read that you can copy the collection, and remove the original -- or remove from an iterator.  Can someone help me understand what I need to do inorder for this method to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you are iterating through the collection of nodes and in some cases removing the actual item from the collection inside the recursive call. You could instead return a boolean flag from the recursive call to sign that the actual item is to be removed, then remove it via `Iterator.remove()` (you need to change the foreach loop to an iterator loop to make this possible).

Replacing the actual item with its only subnode is trickier - you could define a custom class to return more info from the recursive method call, but it starts to become awkward. Or you may consider replacing the recursive call with a loop using e.g. a stack.

Comment: If I return a boolean from the recursive call, I don't see how I can remove it at the right level of the tree

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean remove( int target )
{
    if( find( target ) )    //TreeNode containing target found in Tree
    {
        if( target == root.getInfo( ) ) //target is in root TreeNode
        {
            if( root.isLeaf( ) )
          root = null;
      else if( root.getRight( ) == null )
          root = root.getLeft( );
      else if( root.getLeft( ) == null )
          root = root.getRight( );
      else
      {
          root.getRight( ).getLeftMostNode( ).setLeft( root.getLeft( ) );
          root = root.getRight( );
      }
        }
        else    //TreeNode containing target is further down in Tree
        {
            if( cursor.isLeaf( ) )  //TreeNode containing target has no children
      {
          if( target <= precursor.getInfo( ) )  
              precursor.removeLeftMost( );
          else
        precursor.removeRightMost( );
            }
      else if( cursor.getRight( ) == null ) //TreeNode containing target        
      {                 //has no right subtree
          if( target <= precursor.getInfo( ) )
              precursor.setLeft( cursor.getLeft( ) );
          else
        precursor.setRight( cursor.getLeft( ) );
      }
      else if( cursor.getLeft( ) == null )  //TreeNode containing target
      {                 //has no left subtree
          if( target <= precursor.getInfo( ) )
                    precursor.setLeft( cursor.getRight( ) );
          else
        precursor.setRight( cursor.getRight( ) );
      }
      else  //TreeNode containing target has two subtrees
      {
          cursor.getRight( ).getLeftMostNode( ).setLeft( cursor.getLeft( ) );
          if( target <= precursor.getInfo( ) )
                    precursor.setLeft( cursor.getRight( ) );
          else
        precursor.setRight( cursor.getRight( ) );
            }
        }

        cursor = root;
        return true;
    }
    else    //TreeNode containing target not found in Tree          
        return false;
}
```